# Init with push vue router, back button not working

Tags: vue.js, web, webview, routes, vue-router

The problem seems easier but not working, im working over a spa on webview for apps.

So for example, in some cases I start the web with a main route, like 'localhost/path1/path2'.
So if they press a custom button in topbar (custom component), it goes to 'localhost/path1', here perfect.
The problem is when they press the native back button, or the back arrow in desktop (native).
What happen here is the app is closed or the url is empty in desktop.

I tried to force a push in many ways on load vue with many paths, but not working, I tried to intercept native back and force push to avoid close first time with many paths, but not working anyways.

If someone understand what Im saying and a solve for urls with path/id, and after native back just keep path, instead of close I hope you can help.

Thanks

Comment: this is a very broad topic. For example, in Framework7 it is suggested to `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);` ([here](https://forum.framework7.io/t/how-to-control-back-button-in-mobile/4398)). But this might not work for you, if you use a different solution, for example [VueNative](https://vue-native.io/) (OK, VueNative is not WebView - but there are so many possibilities that it's just a guesswork to try to answer your question)

Comment: backbutton event works ?

Comment: I used it in a couple of projects. You might need to try it out with your most used setup (i.e. Android, iOS, etc.)